# Configure SSL in dbcp2.BasicDataSource

Tags: database, ssl, db2, datasource, truststore

I would like add enable ssl , ssltrustoreLocation and ssltrustorepassword for 
BasicDataSource , can any one tell me how i can add .

```
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();  //NOSONAR
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(Integer.parseInt(dbMaxWaitTime));
    dataSource.setMinIdle(Integer.parseInt(dbMinPoolSize));
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(Integer.parseInt(dbMaxPoolSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether we can have ssltrustoreLocation and password for BasicDataSource. But you can implement it in the server configuration. To connect with DB you have have SSL configured DB schema and can connect with it using user name and password.
In my project, we have configured SSL at the server level and we have SSL db schema for which we are connecting with username and password.